# Change cut view text in CATIA

Tags: vba, drawing, catia

I'm currently working with CATIA V5, and I want to use Macros (VBA), but I have some problems!

My question is: how to change the text of a cut view? (see the picture)

[image]

I tried to use : myView.Texts.item(1) to access to this "text" but **I think that CATIA dont consider it as text**...

I want to change this text without the intervention of the user ( without selections), can I do that?

Comment: I have never worked with catia but have you checked online tutorials like [THIS](http://www.scripting4v5.com/additional-articles/) one? Maybe you can find something there?

Comment: Also do you have any option of recording a macro? Maybe you can then record a macro and do what you want so that you can see how the code works?

Comment: thank you ... i know this website, but can't find the solution ... if i record the macro, it will require the intervention of the user by using selections ...

Comment: @user3503343 no, recording macros is a decent way of identifying the methods of an object you need to use to perform the task. You then edit the recorded code to change the selection / how it identifies the objects.

Comment: When recording, if i double clic and change the value of text "A", the macro records nothing ...

Comment: @user3503343 ah, must be a catia thing then, which I have no experience of. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: Other drafting programs I've worked with refer to this text as a "Section View Label" maybe that will help you narrow down your search.

Comment: thank you, but i found nothing about "Section View Label" in catia ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IME, VBA scripting in drafting workbench is quite tricky at first..."MyTexts" is a collection of DrawingText objects.

```
MyDrawingText.Text = "MyNewTextValue"
```

The main trouble you will have is getting a handle on the specific text object that you want to modify. I found that the best way around this is to either scan the entire DrawingTexts collection in the DrawingView, and apply a unique name, `DrawingText.Name="UniqueObjectName"`, or you create the drawing text from the script and you can more easily get a handle on the DrawingText object to put whatever value you want in there. Creating Unique Names makes your drawing more robust for future scripting

`MyView.Texts.Count` will also be useful to get the item number if the last created DrawingText object(s).

I'm happy to further explain if you need. Good luck!

**Update/Edit:** 
As mentioned above, scripting with the drafting workbench is not always straight forward. It turns out that the callout texts do not exactly live in the `DrawingTexts` collection of a `DrawingView`, but they **do** live somewhere inside the drawing view...In this case, you're trying to edit the "ID" of the section view..That property isn't exposed through VBA either.

There is a *hack/work-around* which is to search the parent view for drawing texts and and then with some logic, which you'll need to come up with, scan the `Selection` for the texts you want to change. You should rename then while you're at it, this way it's easier to come back and find them again.

Here's an example starting with an Object Resolution of the Front View (the parent view of the section view)

```
Sub ChangeCallout()

'---- Begin resolution script for object : Front View

Dim drawingDocument1 As DrawingDocument
Set drawingDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim drawingSheets1 As DrawingSheets
Set drawingSheets1 = drawingDocument1.Sheets

Dim drawingSheet1 As DrawingSheet
Set drawingSheet1 = drawingSheets1.Item("Sheet.1")

Dim drawingViews1 As DrawingViews
Set drawingViews1 = drawingSheet1.Views

Dim drawingView1 As DrawingView
Set drawingView1 = drawingViews1.Item("Front view") 'this is the parent view of the section view

'---- End resolution script

Dim sel As Selection
Set sel = drawingDocument1.Selection
Dim CalloutText As drawingText

sel.Clear 'clear the selection / good practice
sel.Add drawingView1 'add the parent view to the selection
sel.Search "Drafting.Text,sel" 'this will search the current selection for all drawing texts and add them to the selection

Dim thing As Variant
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To sel.Count
    Set thing = sel.Item2(i)
    Set CalloutText = thing.Value
    'do some things/logic here to determine if this is a callout with some Ifs or Case statements
    'CalloutText.Name = "Useful Unique Name"
    'CalloutText.Text = "New Callout Label" 'whatever you want to rename it to
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you GisMofx, but in this cas MyView.Texts.Count gives 0 ... i can't access to this "text"

Comment: @user3503343 Move your mouse pointer over the section callout text and look in the context bar in the lower left. It should say something like _Text.!/Callout (Section View).1..._

Comment: Was trying to edit above comment: @user3503343 Move your mouse pointer over the section callout text and look in the context bar in the very lower left. It should say something like _Text.1/Callout (Section View).1..._ Text.1 is the name you can use in the "GetItem()" function. ALSO, you should use "Object Resolution..." from the Insert menu of the IDE. Choose that then, switch to your drawing and select the section callout letter  with a left click of your mouse and then you'll see the code pop into the IDE with exactly how to get the object. It's an excellent start.

Comment: when i use object resolution, it's gives me a code, when i execute this code it givers me a compilation error ...

Comment: @user3503343 What's the compilation error? On what line? What's the entire code that you're executing?

Comment: @user3503343 I've gotten the same error you're likely experiencing. I've come up with the work-around and _updated my answer_. You should be able to use this as a starting point to do what you need. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: sorry for being late to answer, you method is tricky :D and now the problem is resolved. thank you!

Comment: @user3503343 Great! I'm glad it worked out. If you do more Drafting Automation, you fill find a lot of quirks like this. Also, will you please mark my answer as the correct/accepted answer by pressing the check button next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the text of the cut view is defined by the view name, to change it you should change the view name as describe bellow:

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim oDraw As DrawingDocument
    Set oDraw = CATIA.ActiveDocument

    Dim oSectionView As DrawingView
    Set oSectionView = oDraw.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView

    oSectionView.SetViewName "Prefix ", "B", " Suffix"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For scanning through the callout texts you can use below lines.
This would select the texts belonging to only callout and doesn't scan through all texts.

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim drawingDocument1 As Document
Set drawingDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim selection1 As Selection
Set selection1 = drawingDocument1.Selection

selection1.Search "CATDrwSearch.DrwCallout,all"
selection1.Search "Drafting.Text,sel"

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To selection1.Count

MsgBox selection1.Item(i).Value.text

Next

End Sub
```